# Rails ActionMailer methods confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, actionmailer

I implemented an authentication system using authlogic, and have added password reset functionality as per this tutorial http://github.com/rejeep/authlogic-password-reset-tutorial

It all works, but I am confused as to why it does..

There is this code..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
    reset_perishable_token!
    Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)
  end
end
```

and this

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def password_reset_instructions(user)
    subject      "Password Reset Instructions"
    from         "noreplay@domain.com"
    recipients   user.email
    content_type "text/html"
    sent_on      Time.now
    body         :edit_password_reset_url => edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)
  end
end
```

This line confuses me

```
Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)
```

as the method in the Notifier class is called

```
password_reset_instructions
```

without the `deliver_` bit.

So whats going on here? how come it all works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great Question, A lot of people forget to ask these questions.

Do you notice, that you never really Instantiate your mailer class objects. Your mailer class methods are usually wrapped with this  `deliver_<method_name>`

So internally this uses the concept of `method_missing` in ruby. Suppose you call a certain method in a ruby which doesn't exist for that object, ruby calls the `method_missing` method. Which is defined in the "ActionMailer::Base" code

```
def method_missing(method_symbol, *parameters)#:nodoc:
  case method_symbol.id2name
    when /^create_([_a-z]\w*)/  then new($1, *parameters).mail
    when /^deliver_([_a-z]\w*)/ then new($1, *parameters).deliver!
    when "new" then nil
    else super
  end
end
```

so if a method matches "deliver_" and any combination of lower cases letters, Rails instantiates your Mailer Class ( by calling the "new" )  and sends it with the parameters to the initializer and calls "deliver!" method to finally deliver the mail.

Same goes for "create_<method_name>" type methods

Answer (score 1):

This is the Rails 2 ActionMailer convention.

To deliver an email, use `YourMailerClass.deliver_NAME_OF_THE_METHOD`.
To initialize an email, use `YourMailerClass.create_NAME_OF_THE_METHOD`.

Rails will automatically creates an instance of the Mailer class, call your method and deliver the email object.